# SP JSOM: is there any way to get the group by name instead of getById(10)

Tags: permissions, javascript, client-object-model, groups

is there a way I can use the below with something like getByName(thisGroup), instead of getById(10) in SP 2010 jsom:

```
function setSomeUsers(dataObj, projGroup) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    //instead of this:
    var oGroup = collGroup.getById(10);
    // something like the below
    // var oGroup = collGroup.getByName(projGroup);
    var userCreationInfo = new SP.UserCreationInformation();
    userCreationInfo.set_email(dataObj.userEmail);
    userCreationInfo.set_loginName(dataObj.userLogin);
    userCreationInfo.set_title(dataObj.userTitle);
    this.oUser = oGroup.get_users().add(userCreationInfo);
    clientContext.load(oUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSetAdminsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

}

function onSetAdminsQuerySucceeded() {   
    alert(this.oUser.get_title() + " added.");
}

// plus the failed here
```

so if the above isn't possible, is there a way to get the name and id out of `get_sitegroups()` callback?

appreciated as always!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

AFAIK, it's only possible to use `getByName` in SharePoint 2013, not in 2010. See [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj246409.aspx) for more information

```
 var groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
 visitorsGroup = groupCollection.getByName("SomaGroupName");
```

Comment: thanks Falak. yeah I believe you are correct. so I see what I think is the proper way to get there, another get for the groups in the site and loop through the callback comparing the name, then get the id of the right group and fire this. appreciated!